# using vuetify-google-autocomplete and google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

i'm trying to use vuetify-google-autocomplete in a vue.js project, i did everything like in the tutorial (you can see my github repo: https://github.com/droruri/street-food-app-pwa)
and i'm getting these errors on my console:

```
    [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "googleApiKey"

    found in

    ---> <VuetifyGoogleAutocomplete>
   <VForm>
     <AddRestaurant> at src\components\AddRestaurant.vue
       <VContent>
         <VApp>
           <App> at src\App.vue
             <Root>

    [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "value"

    found in

    ---> <VuetifyGoogleAutocomplete>
   <VForm>
     <AddRestaurant> at src\components\AddRestaurant.vue
       <VContent>
         <VApp>
           <App> at src\App.vue
             <Root>
```

in addition, i'm getting the next errors, that related to google maps API, although I included my api key only once:

```
    You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This 
    may cause unexpected errors.

    Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys 
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-
    messages#no-api-keys
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Your project is using the ALPHA release of `vuetify-google-autocomplete` and the API changed.

Remove the google maps `<script>` tag of your `index.html`.

The error message `[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "googleApiKey"` tells you to provide a property for `VuetifyGoogleAutocomplete` (your Google Maps API key):

```

```
  <vuetify-google-autocomplete
          id="add-restaurant"
          classname="form-control"
          label="כתובת"
          @placechanged="getAddressData"
          google-api-key="my-google-maps-api-key"
        >
        </vuetify-google-autocomplete>
```

```

Release notes: https://github.com/MadimetjaShika/vuetify-google-autocomplete/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.1

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on, @Never is 100% correct.

Furthermore, I have published a [new version](https://github.com/MadimetjaShika/vuetify-google-autocomplete/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.5) of this library earlier today, which resolves a bunch of [issues](https://github.com/MadimetjaShika/vuetify-google-autocomplete/issues) which were noted and makes usage much *simpler*. See the [latest release notes](https://github.com/MadimetjaShika/vuetify-google-autocomplete/releases) for details in usage changes ;)